# Инструменты для оптимизации в с++

Tags: c++, linux, оптимизация, manjaro

Я сейчас изучаю С++ и люблю всё оптимизировать. На Python это сложно сделать, а на С и С++ в самый раз. Желательно библиотеки для измерения быстродействия программы и сколько весит тот или иной тип в С++.

P.S. OC Linux дистрибутив Manjaro(arch)

Comment: Не знаю в тему это или нет, но я для оптимизаций (скорее измерений) использую ... https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTune от Intel

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy она 900$ стоит. Мне явно не по карману

Comment: Google performance tools - позволяет строить целые диаграммы по тому, сколько времени в каком месте программа провела и откуда куда попала. Ну и так же всякие там утечки памяти находить

Comment: `sizeof` -- вот эта штучка, что взвешивает тип

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень рекомендую вышедшую в этом году книгу - "[Оптимизация программ на С++](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/140145932/)" Курта Гантерота.

По первому вопросу - в C++ к вашим услугам библиотека [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono). Пока вы не скажете подробности об операционной системе, нет смысла говорить о каких-то системозависимых вещах. Впрочем, у Гантерота этот вопрос разобран очень неплохо.

По второму - `sizeof(type)` даст вам размер типа - у текущего компилятора, при текущем выравнивании и т.д.

При оптимизации нужно оптимизировать самое узкое место (см. [закон Амдала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0)) - и здесь без профайлера для выявления такого места обойтись очень трудно, потому что ничто так не врет, как "здравый смысл".

И главное - учтите, что **главная оптимизация - это правильно подобрать алгоритм**, так что не проходите мимо этой темы. Оптимизировать O(n^2) до O(n) при наличии решения O(1) (пробегал тут недавно такой вопрос :)) - это не оптимизация... Тем более глупо ускорение при помощи какого-нибудь ассемблера плохого алгоритма...